# margin-top with % doesn't work

Tags: css

I have a column with some rows.

Code:

```
<div class="col-fluid">
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
    <div class="height1">1</div>
</div>
```

So I assign a `margin-top` for each `height1` class:

```
.col-fluid > [class*="height"]:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 0.699301%;
}
```

Now, there's a problem with that `margin-top`, in some height sizes (that I don't know them exactly) seems `margin-top` doesn't work.

See first left column in this screenshot:

[image: margin-top doesn't work]

But is another size, it works:

[image: margin-top Works]

What's the problem? Is there any problem with my `margin-top` size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think , it is better to do that :

```
<div class="col-fluid">
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="height1">1</div></div>
</div>

.col-fluid div.container
{
  padding-top:10px;
}
```